# editor.action.indentLines does not work in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

According to the default keyboard shortcuts documentation there is this shortcut:

```
{ 
  "key": "cmd+]",
  "command": "editor.action.indentLines",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly" 
}
```

However it does not indent when I use it and adding a tab character instead.
I assume it is supposed to reindent the line according to the indentation rules (I use 4 spaces) - is that correct?

Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that command will respect whatever indentation settings you have enabled for the current document. Try looking in the status bar for the current indentation setting:

Spaces: [image]

Tabs: [image]

Click on the spaces/tabs item to change the indentation setting for the file.

If you are still seeing unexpected behavior, [please open a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new)

Comment: ok I understand now. I have a question - is there a way in VS code to indent lines like emacs lets you do it - lets say if your cursor is in the middle of the line and you use TAB it will indent the line according you the previous line and the rules of the indentation of the opened file. I could not find how one can do that in VS code, only way to do it is using editor.action.indentLines which will only add that many chars in front of the cursor.